# Problem with putting two tikzpictures next to each other

Tags: latex, tex

I have a problem with putting two tikzpictures next to each other.

I have tried using minipages too, but that ain't working too.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left = 23mm, bottom = 24mm, top = 24mm, right = 29mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning}
\usepackage{subfig}
```

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    
        \centering
    
        \begin{subfloat}[lfig1] {

        \centering

            \begin{tikzpicture}
            
                    \draw[thin, ->] (1.2,0) -- (1.2,5.4) node[below left]{$\phi_2(t)$};
                    \draw[thin, ->] (0,1.2) -- (5.4,1.2) node[below left]{$\phi_1(t)$};
                    \draw[very thick, blue, ->] (1.2,1.2) -- (1.2,4.15) node[black][midway, right=1mm]{$s_2$};
                    \draw[very thick,red,->] (1.2,1.2) -- (4.15,1.2) node[black][midway, above=1mm]{$s_1$};
                    \draw[thin, dashed] (1.2,4.2) -- (4.2,1.2) node[midway, above right]{$\sqrt{2E_b}$};
            
            \end{tikzpicture}
            
        }
            
        \end{subfloat}
        
        \hspace{10pt}       
        
        \begin{subfloat}[lfig2] {

        \centering
        
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            
                \draw[thin, ->] (0,1.2) -- (8.4,1.2) node[below left]{$\phi_1(t)$};
                \draw[thin, ->] (4.2,0) -- (4.2,3.4) node[below left]{$\phi_2(t)$};
                \draw[thick, blue, ->] (4.2,1.2) -- (1.25,1.2) node[midway, above=1mm]{$s_2$};
                \draw[thick, red, ->] (4.2,1.2) -- (7.15,1.2) node[midway, above=1mm]{$s_1$};
            
            \end{tikzpicture}
        
        }       
        
        \end{subfloat}
        
        \caption{captionfig1}
        \label{Slika:fig1}
    
    \end{figure}
```

So, I need to put these two graphs in the same 'row'. I have tried using minipages with different sized \linewidth, but that lead me nowhere.

I need it to be shown like this: https://prnt.sc/CM8kFW-DvRQZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empty lines in latex denote the end of a paragraph. If you don't want a line break, don't end the current paragraph by adding all these empty lines.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left = 23mm, bottom = 24mm, top = 24mm, right = 29mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning}
\usepackage{subfig}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{subfloat}[lfig1] {
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
   
            \draw[thin, ->] (1.2,0) -- (1.2,5.4) node[below left]{$\phi_2(t)$};
            \draw[thin, ->] (0,1.2) -- (5.4,1.2) node[below left]{$\phi_1(t)$};
            \draw[very thick, blue, ->] (1.2,1.2) -- (1.2,4.15) node[black][midway, right=1mm]{$s_2$};
            \draw[very thick,red,->] (1.2,1.2) -- (4.15,1.2) node[black][midway, above=1mm]{$s_1$};
            \draw[thin, dashed] (1.2,4.2) -- (4.2,1.2) node[midway, above right]{$\sqrt{2E_b}$};
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{subfloat}
\hspace{10pt}       
\begin{subfloat}[lfig2] {
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
        \draw[thin, ->] (0,1.2) -- (8.4,1.2) node[below left]{$\phi_1(t)$};
        \draw[thin, ->] (4.2,0) -- (4.2,3.4) node[below left]{$\phi_2(t)$};
        \draw[thick, blue, ->] (4.2,1.2) -- (1.25,1.2) node[midway, above=1mm]{$s_2$};
        \draw[thick, red, ->] (4.2,1.2) -- (7.15,1.2) node[midway, above=1mm]{$s_1$};
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
}       
\end{subfloat}
\caption{captionfig1}
\label{Slika:fig1}

\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]